# Jquery client side validation with jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, datepicker

The validation used to be working, but I switched to using datepicker.  I have noticed that the client side validation doesn't always get hit.  It may take a few date selections for the break point to get reached.  But, if you select a date and are still in the text box and hit enter, it works every time.

I do have the correct scripts loading and in the view. My method for validation is just

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CheckEndDate(DateTime CourseEndDate, DateTime CourseStartDate)
{
    return Json(CourseStartDate < CourseEndDate);
}
```

My model attribute

```
[Remote("CheckEndDate", "Course", AdditionalFields = "CourseStartDate", HttpMethod = "POST",
    ErrorMessage = "Must end after Start Date")]
```

View stuff

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>
@{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

    if (Model != null) {
        date = (System.DateTime) Model;
    }
}
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:MMM dd, yyyy}", date),
  new { @class = "datefield", type = "text"  })

<td class="table-row">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CourseStartDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseStartDate)
</td>
<td class="table-row">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CourseEndDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseEndDate)
</td>
//Date field datepicker hookup
$('.datefield').datepicker({dateFormat:'M dd, yy'});
```

To re-note, I wasn't using a datepicker, except for googles, and wanted a crossbrowser one.  It was working on every date change.  Now it works half the time or only on pressing enter.

Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

In my projet i did my validation like that :

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
     //Your validation goes here
     if(!good){
       ev.setValue("");
       alert("Your date is invalide!");
     }
});
```